# How to read file of size more than 100 MB efficiently in Java

Tags: java, apache-commons

Hey I am using Java 8 in my spring boot application. I am getting data from apache server through an HTTP call. Data size sometime is more than 100 MB (more than 100 000 lines). I need to convert that data into list of string. For smaller data below code is working but for larger it is giving

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

This is how i am converting the data into List of string.

```
List<String> lines = null;
try {
    String data = con.sendGet();

    
    if(data==null)
        throw new UserAuthException("diff is not available at the location");

    else {
        diff.setLineAsString(data);
        lines = IOUtils.readLines(new StringReader(data));
        System.out.println("lines = IOUtils.readLines(new StringReader(data));");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does IOUtils run in memory? what is the efficient way to read it?

Comment: Read and process it one line at a time. Consider using a `Scanner`.

Comment: Can u pls provide me some example?

Comment: What is the return type  of `con.sendGet()`?

Comment: @AT refer this..> https://www.novixys.com/blog/java-reading-large-file-efficiently/

Comment: line separated string.

Above code can also be output

Comment: @AT so `con.sendGet()` returns a 100Mb String? Then you're hosed. Don't waste your time working with it. Anything that returns a gigantic String is an unscaleable and unuseable API; it needs to return an `InputStream` or similar. Consider using Flux.

Comment: Ok If i do read it into input stream also then how can i proceed?

Comment: @AT  `Scanner s = new  Scanner(inputStream); while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {String line = scanner.nextLine(); doSomethingWithLine(line);}`

Comment: Scanner is slow. 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data));
    String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         //
          }
Any thing faster than that?

Comment: Two things. 1. What are you doing with each line? Are you building a (massive) collection of things line by line? If so your OOM errors ain’t going to go away. 2. How **time**-critical is this does this need to be? Could you write the 100Mb string to a temp file and read that line by line (i.e. make the filesystem your buffer, not RAM).

Answer (score 2):

Lets go in utmost details.

**Reading in Memory**

The standard way of reading the lines of the file is in memory – both Guava and Apache Commons IO provide a quick way to do just that:

```
Files.readLines(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);

FileUtils.readLines(new File(path));
```

The problem with this approach is that all the file lines are kept in memory – which will quickly lead to OutOfMemoryError if the File is large enough.

**For example – reading a ~1Gb file:**

```
@Test
public void givenUsingGuava_whenIteratingAFile_thenWorks() throws IOException {
    String path = ...
    Files.readLines(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);
}
```

This starts off with a small amount of memory being consumed: (~0 Mb consumed)

> **[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Total Memory: 128 Mb**
> **[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Free Memory: 116 Mb**

However, after the full file has been processed, we have at the end: (~2 Gb consumed)

> **[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Total Memory: 2666 Mb**
> **[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Free Memory: 490 Mb**

Which means that about 2.1 Gb of memory are consumed by the process – the reason is simple – the lines of the file are all being stored in memory now.

It should be obvious by this point that **keeping in memory the contents of the file will quickly exhaust the available memory** – regardless of how much that actually is.

What's more, **we usually don't need all of the lines in the file in memory at once** – instead, we just need to be able to iterate through each one, do some processing and throw it away. So, this is exactly what we're going to do – iterate through the lines without holding all of them in memory.

**Streaming Through the File**

Let's now look at a solution – we're going to use a java.util.Scanner to run through the contents of the file and retrieve lines serially, one by one:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(line);
    }
    // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**This solution will iterate through all the lines in the file – allowing for processing of each line – without keeping references to them – and in conclusion, without keeping them in memory: (~150 Mb consumed)**

> **[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Total Memory: 763 Mb**
> **[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Free Memory: 605 Mb**

**Streaming With Apache Commons IO**

The same can be achieved using the Commons IO library as well, by using the `custom LineIterator` provided by the library:

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

Since the entire file is not fully in memory – this will also result in pretty conservative memory consumption numbers: (~150 Mb consumed)

> **[main] INFO  o.b.java.CoreJavaIoIntegrationTest - Total Memory: 752 Mb**
> **[main] INFO  o.b.java.CoreJavaIoIntegrationTest - Free Memory: 564 Mb**

Code snippet available [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/core-java-modules/core-java-io-2)

Comment: Thanks for such deep explanation. But i am getting the response from Apache as string data. So do you want me to save it into file then read it ?

Comment: you can certainly change that. Having response in String isnt mandatory. Above example you can blindly copy paste just by changing file path. :) @AT

Comment: It is too much of asking. SO i have to receive get call output in a file. Then proceed with what u suggested.

Comment: There is a difference. You were reading file using `IOUtils`. In example I have shared I used `FileUtils`. Or If you are confused I will suggest add some more code to your question @AT

Answer (score 1):

Usually while consuming a sufficiently large file, you end up with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

If you wanted to convert larger files into `List<String>`, there are various approaches,

```
1. Loading a Binary File in Chunks

try(BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathname)))
{
    byte[] bbuf = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(bbuf)) != -1) {
        // process data here: bbuf[0] thru bbuf[len - 1]
    }
}
```

Through readLine

```
2. Reading a Text File Line By Line

try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathname))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // process line here.
    }
}
```

Through Scanner,

```
3. Using a Scanner
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(pathname))) {
    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        // process line here.
    }
}
```

Through Streams,

```
4. With Java 8 Streams

List<String> alist = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathname))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also refer this [LINK](https://www.novixys.com/blog/java-reading-large-file-efficiently/)